How to write this Excel in-cell formula "properly" and more compact?
Checking per row if column D = true, then returning as string the corresponding cells in column B and C.
I can write the below manually just fine, but it's not great for adding extra rows later and I know there has to be a better way to do it, I just don't know what phrase to search for to help me find out.
[...]
&if(D10=true(),B10&": "&C10&char(10),"")
&if(D11=true(),B11&": "&C11&char(10),"")
&if(D12=true(),B12&": "&C12&char(10),"")
&if(D13=true(),B13&": "&C13&char(10),"")
&if(D14=true(),B14&": "&C14&char(10),"")
[...]


You want all the results in one cell?

@Excellor Results all in one cell, correct.

The following should work:
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, IF(D10:D14=TRUE, B10:B14 & ": " & C10:C14, ""))

And traditionally, just to make things more awkward for anyone trying to maintain this formula in the future:
=LET(
    InputRange, B1:D5,
    Delimiter, CHAR(10),
    BColumn, INDEX(InputRange,,1),
    CColumn, INDEX(InputRange,,2),
    DColumn, INDEX(InputRange,,3),
    IsTrue, IF(DColumn=TRUE, BColumn & ": " & CColumn, ""),
    JoinText, TEXTJOIN(Delimiter, TRUE, IsTrue),
    JoinText
)


=TRUE is not necessary. =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, IF(D10:D14, B10:B14 & ": " & C10:C14, ""))

Legendary, thank you. Much better than what I had initially.

More compact:
=CONCAT(REPT(B10:B14&": "&C10:C14&CHAR(10),--D10:D14))


@nkalvi No magic. --D10:D14) converts FALSE/TRUE to 0/1. REPT gives a sting if true and nothing else.

You can try the following:
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, FILTER(B10:B14&": "&C10:C14, D10:D14=TRUE))

